# Symmetry not working?

Tags: edit-mode, sculpting

so I'm brand new to blender(and 3d programs in general) so I could be missing something obvious, so please forgive me, but I'm trying to sculpt a face in edit mode and symmetry does not seem to be working? I tried to google it but the offered solutions don't seem to be working for me? I made sure to get my object 0,0,0, and I placed my cursor there too? I have X and y symmetry turned on.[image]

Comment: it looks like an icosphere, it might not be a symmetrical object, try to test with another object

Comment: It is a icosphere! It never occurred to never occurred to me that could be the case! I'll try the other spherical option thank you so much!

Comment: Actually my bad it's symmetrical, you just need to rotate it 90° on the Z axis to make it symmetrical   ;)

Comment: If you are brand new to blender start with the right foot and work with quad based topology instead of just triangles. Use a UV sphere or a cube as your starting mesh instead of an icosphere. You will find that working with triangles is a lot harder. There are countless "tutorials" out there on how to create a head. Watch them first.

Comment: Thank you to everyone! I switched to uv sphere and it fixed it immediately! I didn't realize triangles would make things more difficult and just chose it because it seemed like less faces, but I've learned my lesson.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you've created a icosphere which, by default, is not created symmetrical on the X axis but on the Y axis, so just rotate it 90° in the Z axis in *Edit* mode and you're good.

Comment: I so totally didn't know the icosphere is shorter on the x axis than it is on the y axis, but I just confirmed that this is indeed the case. I was shocked. I always just assumed it was a perfect sphere, but just made exclusively out of triangles. So now I'm wondering why it's not a perfect sphere.

Comment: @R-800 The x and y size is actually the same when using 3 and more subdivisions. 1 and 2 subdivisions just don't have enough geometry :).